# Understanding parentage in environment diagrams

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I'm confused about defining the parent of a function as the frame in which the function is defined as it pertains to a HOF that defines a function and then drops out of scope.

```
def foo(x):
    print(f'foo x: {x}')
    return x

def bar(f):
    print(f'bar f: {f}')
    def bat(y):
        print(f'bat f(y): {f(y)}')
        return y
    return bat

new_func = bar(foo)
# f1    bar         parent = global
#       f = foo
#       return bat
# Doesn't f1 cease to exist here? Out of scope

new_func(5)
# f2    new_func    parent = f1
#       y = 5
#       return y
# If f1 is out of scope, how can the parent of f2 be f1?
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess I am confused by your question regarding parentage of functions.  Your example code doesn't clarify the confusion for the following reasons:

1. foo is a defined function, the definition of this function will remain in scope for the duration of the function/script within which it is defined.
2. bar is a second defined function. the definition of this function will remain in scope for the duration of the function/script within which it is defined.
3. the instruction `new_func = bar(foo)` simply defines a new pointer to the previously defined function foo.

So I guess to answer your question neither foo, bar or new_func cease to exist in your example code assuming all are defined within the same scope.

To my way of thinking, there is no lineage created between these functions, so any assertion that they go out of scope is incorrect.

Hopefully, this answers your question